# My Cron stops automatically after serveral days whether I set it for unlimited time execution

Tags: php, cron, ubuntu-16.04, plesk

I'm using PHP as a service. It is needed to run continuously. So I made a PHP script with unlimited time execution with `set_time_limit(0)` and run an infinity while loop to process my service time to time without any delay.

Then I run the cron to execute the file and eventually it starts working.

But unfortunately it gets stopped after 5~6 days running. It happened 3 times. In this case what can I do?

I'm using a VPS server with ubuntu-16 and Plesk for maintenance.

Comment: Are you logging what happens during its execution?

Comment: Your question is very confused; you seem to be using specific terminology innappropriately to describe a software system which is flawed by design. If your from jobs are not running then the first place to look is on your server, not ask us. Check your friend, crontab and logs.

Comment: @chris85 logged everything. But suddenly it all stops. It is not finding my db config file which is a php file. And it didn't connect to the database and stopped working. The cron return mail throw me PHP error that it didn't able to connect my database. Thats it. But I don't know why this thing is happening.

Comment: @symcbean Dear, I did all I can with my server. But in my server there is no issue. It works fine for around 5 days and then stopped. If I start it again it runs for another 5 days and then same. So I asked if someone did already follow the same problem already and if he solves it. So that I can be benefited from his advice. Thats all. 
** Here cron stops, not server

Comment: So it connects for 5 days, then on day 5 you get errors about the included file not being there? Please add more the question, sounds like we are missing information.

Comment: Whoops, autocorrect changed 'crond' to 'friend' in my comment. There is no entity 'cron' on a Unix system, so that you report it stops is not very meaningful.

Comment: @symcbean Just for your kind information
https://www.google.com/search?q=%27cron%27+on+a+Unix+system&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Comment: @chris85, I searched again and found out that it might be with using 'localhost' for connection.So I changed it to '127.0.0.1'. Now finger crossed. But it is strange that it works for 5 days. Another interesting thing is I've another cron running with the same config. (Basically I started both at the same time,just one stopped execution)